# php combo list values from function

Tags: php, html, html-select

I wanted the `category_list` function value to be inside my combo box but it's not working. Any gurus out there to help me? thanks!
this is working

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $xx['evt_category'];?>:</td>
    <td>
        <select name="cat" id="cat">
            <?php if ($_SESSION['uid']!=1) {category_list($cat);} ?>
            </select>

    </td>

</tr>
```

this is not working

```
echo "<td><select id=\"cat\" name=\"cat\"></td>\n";
echo "<option value='".category_list($cat)."</option>\n";
echo "</select>\n";
```

Comment: What's not working? What does `category_list` do?

Comment: Please **edit** your question and add the code there. Comments are a bad place for lots of code.

Comment: category_list returns values from a table it's perfectly working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your first example is working, then this should be working:

```
echo '<td><select id="cat" name="cat">';
echo category_list($cat);
echo '</select></td>';
```